# How to download .svg file from this page?

Tags: svg, download

I need to download the "Municipalities in Bosnia and Herzegovina.svg" (map) file from [this page](http://izbori.ba/rezultati_izbora_2016/?resId=13&langId=2#/8/0/0), but I have no idea how to download it, i.e. to find a link to the image on the page. I found `sodipodi:docname="Municipalities in Bosnia and Herzegovina.svg"` in the source code, but that still doesn't help me. Could someone link to the svg file and perhaps explain how they deduced where the file is stored?

Answer (score 13):

Assuming you have the rights to use the map. **Make sure you do.**

The SVG is embedded into the code of the page. You need to cut and paste it from the page source.

The following instructions are for Chrome. Other browsers will be similar.

1. Mouse over the light grey area of the map.
2. Right-click, then select "Inspect" from the menu
3. The browser web tools pane should open with the `<svg>` element selected.
4. Ctrl-C to copy
5. Paste into your favourite text editor.

Answer (score 9):

"Save Page As"

- Chrome(right click)
- Firefox (menu/Alt or Ctrl + S), then choose the "just SVG" option in the dropdown menu.
- Internet Explorer (get Firefox or Chrome, its about time!)

Comment: I don't have an "Just SVG"-option in my Save Page As-dialog in Firefox. Where is it?

Answer (score 5):

An easy way to download the SVG is using a browser extension. For example, on the Chrome browser there is the [SVG Export](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/svg-export/naeaaedieihlkmdajjefioajbbdbdjgp/related?hl=en-GB) extension which allows you to view & download the SVGs on a given page. Of course, always make sure that you have the rights/permissions to download the SVGs.